# How to pass data from one component to another trough window.href in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

I have a component A where I get the selected dates. I want to pass the selected dates to another component B through window.location.href.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: take a look at vue router. Besides, you can always natively manipulate the url.

Comment: Can you provide more information here ? Because you could essentially pass the data with emit/props probably: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props Otherwise, you could indeed use vue-router with `router.push` as seen here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: if you are using vue 3 you could take a look at [provide/inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity)

Comment: @witt it is also available with Vue2 but not a great idea in this case.

Comment: Ah okay. Yes, then it is better to solve this via the router options.